# Cannot connect to IIS site using anything but localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: iis, iis-7, localhost

I have finally [painstakingly] setup a locally hosted site using IIS7.

I am now currently able to connect to it via http://localhost/mediaorganizer/ or http://127.0.0.1/mediaorganizer/ on the host machine.

However when I try to use the IP address of the host machine on itself or another machine on the network, I get the following error:

> refused to connect error

I have searched up and down with no luck. I have setup the firewall rules for in-bound, they are set for TCP on port 80, using World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In). I have setup bindings in IIS as http, All Unassigned, 80. I also made sure to start the site while running IIS Manager as administrator. But all with no luck.

I feel I maybe missing a final process to achieve my desired effect. I've spent a solid day on this project and would appreciate any help.

**Recent Logs**

> ## Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
>
> ## Version: 1.0
>
> ## Date: 2016-08-28 02:33:55
>
> ## Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri streamid sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
>
> 2016-08-28 02:33:55 127.0.0.1 50211 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 02:36:29 127.0.0.1 50356 127.0.0.1 64900 HTTP/1.1 GET / - 400 - Hostname -
>   2016-08-28 02:37:30 127.0.0.1 50331 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 03:02:37 127.0.0.1 50593 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 03:06:33 127.0.0.1 50607 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 03:10:03 127.0.0.1 50678 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:16:54 127.0.0.1 50821 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:19:14 127.0.0.1 50864 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:32:17 127.0.0.1 50948 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:34:32 127.0.0.1 50999 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:42:10 127.0.0.1 51036 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /mediaorganizer/about.aspx - 404 - NotFound -
>   2016-08-28 05:44:30 127.0.0.1 51041 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 05:46:35 127.0.0.1 51059 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>
> ## Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
>
> ## Version: 1.0
>
> ## Date: 2016-08-28 06:00:59
>
> ## Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri streamid sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
>
> 2016-08-28 06:00:59 127.0.0.1 50005 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /MediaOrganizer/ - 404 - NotFound -
>   2016-08-28 06:09:42 127.0.0.1 50188 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 06:09:47 127.0.0.1 50183 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 06:12:58 127.0.0.1 50205 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 06:12:58 127.0.0.1 50208 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 06:16:14 127.0.0.1 50277 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 06:16:14 127.0.0.1 50279 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 17:59:24 127.0.0.1 51430 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
>   2016-08-28 17:59:24 127.0.0.1 51428 127.0.0.1 80 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -

Comment: Since it's not even working locally can you check the httperr logs (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR). How is the behavior with the machine name ?

Comment: Machine name does not work as well. Also the log file shows no new errors when trying to access the site using the machine name or IP.

Comment: What is the status code? Would be good if you can browse with machine name and paste the log here.

Comment: Don't see a code or anything. Doing this in chrome and it's the page that says "This site can’t be reached david-pc refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" Logs will be added to original post.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to correct the issue. Turns out I had configured IIS to listen to IP Address 127.0.0.1 through command prompt. I had to undo this by opening command prompt and enter in the following commands.

```
netsh
http
show iplisten <- just to confirm it was there, and it was.
delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Now I am able to use the PC name and it's actual IP address to access my local IIS site.

Comment: Totally forgot about IP listen list.Missed my 15pts...:(

Comment: I was experiencing this same issue and when I executed these commands the list of addresses was empty so I added the IP address of my machine and then I was able to access the locally hosted websites via the machine-name.  Strange because it was working without this previously but now it seems to need it?  Or was it there and somehow magically got removed?

Comment: And actually... the list was not empty but instead contained the ipv6 version of localhost -- `::` -- which was the problem.  Once I removed it and the ipv4 address of my machine all was back to normal (I could access the sites through either localhost or the machine-name).

Answer (score 2):

I do see a 404 - NotFound twice

> 2016-08-28 05:42:10 127.0.0.1 51036 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET
>   /mediaorganizer/about.aspx - 404 - NotFound -
>
> 2016-08-28 06:00:59 127.0.0.1 50005 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET
>   /MediaOrganizer/ - 404 - NotFound -

This happens when you have binding mapped to a specific hostname in IIS. Something like below . So check this and remove Host name if you have any.

If it's empty probably delete the binding and recreate without any Host name.

Another place to check is host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) . Comment out if you see anything like below by adding a # before

```
127.0.0.1       localhost //These should be commented out
::1             localhost //These should be commented out
```

[image]

Comment: The bindings do not have a hostname i.e. localhost nor does my host file have anything listed in it. It was already commented out. The strange thing is those 404 could be from my previous attempts, 127.0.0.1 now works locally whereas the actual IP and PC name do not. I'm going to attempt to re-create the site with your information to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Alright so it did not work. But I noticed I cannot "Create New Site" in Visual Studio when creating a new site. The only option available is to "Create New Web Application" under the Default Web Site for IIS Sites. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Got it, see my answer  below. Was stupid and an amateur move on my part as to what the issue was.